# Django Login Message with LoginView

Tags: python, django

I am a bit confused on why my LoginView message is not pulling the users login name. I have tried a few different ways and it either will say 'Welcome Anonymous User' or 'Welcome' (not adding anything). I have tried a few different methods and the results are the same each way I try to solve it. My code is as follows:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    success_message = 'Welcome'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Add message here"""
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, f"{self.success_message} {self.request.user}")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This one will say 'Welcome AnonymousUser', if I change the code to {self.request.user.username} it just will say 'Welcome'

also have tried

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {self.request.user}')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This one will flash the message of 'Welcome Anonymous User'. If I change the code to f'Welcome {self.request.user.username}' then the message displayed is just 'Welcome'

I am not really sure why these aren't working so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you try `form.get_user()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your user *isn't* logged in yet when you write that line. The user is logged in to the request after you have called `super().form_valid(form)`. What you can do to get the user object is to call `form.get_user()`:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.get_user()
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {user}')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Ah thank you for the explanation, that makes perfect sense. This works great

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a simple way to solve this is to swap the `super()` call and sending the message:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        messages.success(self.request, f'Welcome {self.request.user}')
        return response
```

The response of a successful POST request with `form_valid` is a redirect, so that means that we do not need to render the message in the `response` here. It will make a redirect, and the redirect URL will then render the message.

Comment: Wow thank you for the response, this works as well. Very interesting solution to my problem, I would not have thought about it in this way. It's a shame I cannot accept two answers to this question (unless I am mistaken)